# How to call class method from mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a mailer in the directory:
`/my_app/app/mailers`

My code in this mailer is:

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'todd@myemail.com'
  include Reports::OrderReport

  def welcome_email
    email = params[:email]
    mail(to: email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
    sheet = OrderReport.new
    sheet.create_workbook
  end

end
```

For the emails that go out from this mailer I need to attach an excel report that's getting generated from a class defined in `/my_app/app/reports` and the code in this class looks like this:

```
class OrderReport
  require 'axlsx'
  attr_reader :shop, :order_workbook

  def initialize
    workbook_instance = Axlsx::Package.new
    @order_workbook = workbook_instance.workbook
  end

  def create_workbook
    order_workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Basic Worksheet") do |sheet|
      sheet.add_row ["First Column", "Second", "Third"]
      sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
      sheet.add_row ['     preserving whitespace']
    end
    order_workbook.serialize("test_book.xlsx")
  end
end
```

But when I try and run my mailer with this:

```
MyMailer.with(email: "this_email@gmail.com").welcome_email.deliver_now
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MyMailer::Reports
        from app/mailers/my_mailer.rb:3:in `<class:MyMailer>'
        from app/mailers/my_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from (irb):1
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The issue is that your `Reports` constant can't be found for some reason. Where is that defined? Make sure it's loaded; `include ::Reports::OrderReport` may help resolve any ambiguities.

Comment: Hmm, didn't work.. but `Reports` is the folder where my class `OrderReport` is defined.. if that helps?

Comment: 1) the folder name means nothing, you have to make sure it’s included in the load path though. 2) in order to namespace OrderReport you have to define it like this: `class Reports::OrderReport`

Comment: Have you tried running it without the include statement altogether?

Comment: @NamanWadhwa yep that's what I thought.. but when I don't include or require I get this error:NameError: uninitialized constant MyMailer::OrderReport
        from app/mailers/my_mailer.rb:9:in `welcome_email'
        from (irb):1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include `class OrderReport`
(Rails expects module to be included)
Just removing   `include Reports::OrderReport` should solve the issue
Also you should rename class to `Reports::OrderReport` in /my_app/app/reports/order_report.rb and in you mailer due to Rails file naming

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make some changes to the way you use the names of the classes. The naming should be consistent. You could also wrap the OrderReport class in a report Module if you like.

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'todd@myemail.com'
  include Reports::OrderReport

  def welcome_email
    email = params[:email]
    mail(to: email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
    sheet = Reports::OrderReport.new
    sheet.create_workbook
  end

end

class Reports::OrderReport
  require 'axlsx'
  attr_reader :shop, :order_workbook

  def initialize
    workbook_instance = Axlsx::Package.new
    @order_workbook = workbook_instance.workbook
  end

  def create_workbook
    order_workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Basic Worksheet") do |sheet|
      sheet.add_row ["First Column", "Second", "Third"]
      sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
      sheet.add_row ['     preserving whitespace']
    end
    order_workbook.serialize("test_book.xlsx")
  end
end
```